# Allow users to download files from Google Drive on my behalf

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I would first like to apologize if this question is a duplicate; perhaps I'm not being able to word what I need correctly because I really couldn't find a solution for my need after several hours of research...

I need logged users of my application (PHP, Laravel 5.7) to be able to download files from a specific folder on my Google Drive on my behalf; of course, without having my credentials, but I'm being unable to figure out how to make the request; all the examples I found were to allow users to download their own files after they authenticate with their credentials. Since Google Drive API uses OAUTH2, I thought I could just send a request to some endpoint with Authentication header bearing my token and the "file id" and the download would start but after scavenging the docs I still couldn't find this endpoint.

EDIT: Thanks to Osama Ibrahim for pointing to me the above endpoint.

Sorry for long text, tl;dr:
I need to know how my application can download a file on my drive programatically, requesting a token with my credentials without having to go through the google login UI.

Comment: Did you check the documentation?
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads

Comment: Yes, what I'm not being able to find is the endpoint which I can send my email and password to in order to get the access token required for the request in this example... all examples I found seem to use the Google UI that requests the user's credentials, but I want the application to make the request on my behalf, not the user's.

Comment: It this possible, @OsamaIbrahim ?

Comment: You will need to obtain a Refresh Token for your account and embed it in your php app. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention/19766913#19766913

Comment: OMG YES, thank you pinoyyid!

Do you mind writing an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @MatheusAdorniDardenne no idea bro.